# Checkboxlist is added programatically, having issues

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript

Code keeps will only add one first checked name to check box and will not add others,  However it keeps adding the checkboxlist everytime the btn is clicked. Not sure why this is happening.  Please Help

```
Partial Class ShermanZone
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            CheckBox()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub CheckBox() Handles CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Jeff"))
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Kristin"))
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Scott"))
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Karri"))
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Amy"))
    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnClick_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click
        Dim strTextBox As String = String.Empty

        For Each picked As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
            If picked.Selected Then
                If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strTextBox) Then
                    strTextBox = picked.Value
                Else
                    strTextBox += ("," & picked.Value)
                End If
            End If
            Exit For
        Next picked

        txtOutput.Text = strTextBox
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

So instead:

```
Protected Sub CheckBox() Handles CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Jeff"))
    ' ..... '
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Amy"))
End Sub
```

this:

```
Protected Sub CheckBox()
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Jeff"))
    ' ..... '
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Amy"))
End Sub
```

Otherwise it's also triggered on postbacks and adds all items again to the list.

Apart from that you can simplify your button-click handler where you append the selected items' value:

```
Protected Sub btnClick_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnClick.Click
    Dim picked = From item In CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)()
               Where item.Selected
               Select item.Value

    txtOutput.Text = String.Join(",", picked)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on that.  Worked perfect, still a newbie at this.